# Migrating actionbarsherlock to version 4.0.2 (from 3.5)

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am migrating my app that uses actionbarsherlock 3.5 to actionbarsherlock 4.2. Almost everything is working, but i have a problem with onPrepareOptionsMenu((android.view.Menu) menu);

I need to add some items to actionbarsherlock at runtime. I do this on:

public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu).

The problem is that this method expects an android.view.Menu as param. So, i am calling:

super.onPrepareOptionsMenu((android.view.Menu) menu);

This does not works and my menu is never created. Everything worked fine with actionbarsherlock 3.5.

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shouldn't expect `android.view.Menu`. Are you extending from `Sherlock(Fragment)Activity`/`SherlockFragment`?

Comment: Just to add to this.. Make sure you remove imports to android.view.Menu and replace them with the ABS classes where appropriate (ex. com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu) . A good idea would be to delete the method that's giving you problems and re-implement it using the eclipse Override/Implement methods. That way all of the imports are automatically generated for you. Make sure you save the code inside of the method before you delete it :P Then just paste it back when you implement the proper one